# Does a lock do the same for synchronized?

Tags: java, locking, synchronized, reentrantlock

Let's say I have a thread-safe bank account class looks like this

```java
class BankAccount {

    private long balance;

    public synchronized long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(long amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(long amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Does using a lock make a same effect?

```java
class BankAccount {

    private long balance;

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public long getBalance() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            return balance;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void deposit(long amount) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            balance += amount;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void withdraw(long amount) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            balance -= amount;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They have the same effect. Locks are introduced for more flexible synchronization operation.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> ReentrantLock: A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

[From the official documentation for reentrant locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)